# Which animation style is used in Kingdom?

Tags: anime-production, kingdom

I've been watching *Kingdom* and *Kingdom: Season 2* for a while now and I can't help but be a bit distracted by how differently it is animated compared to most anime these days.

Which animation style is used to achieve this more 3D-like feeling? And why did they pick this over the usual animation style?

[image: sample image from Kingdom]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series uses CGI, notably a combination of 3d objects with 2d illustrations (more so in the Second season then in the first). This has been common practice in the industry for a while (both to improve quality and save on labor). Most production use cel shaders or rotoscoping the model to mask the disconnect between the two dimensions.

A notable examples with less distinctions in recent anime are Berserker from Fate/Zero:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7OYPb3fTP0

and the new Code Geass series:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOYerOT_Wpc#t=48

Answer (score 4):

That looks to be cel shading which is "designed to make 3-D computer graphics appear to be flat".  - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cel_shading)

[image]